# Arranging people with condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given $X$ boys and $Y$ girls, what are the number of ways to arrange them in a row such that no more than $Z$ individuals of the same gender are adjacent?

Example:

- Given $1$ boy, $1$ girl and $Z=1$, there is $2$ (the arrangements $BG, GB$)
- Given $2$ boys, $1$ girl and $Z=1$, there is $1$ (the arrangement $BGB$)

I tried calculating total number of combinations first $\frac{\left(X+Y\right)!}{X!Y!}$ then deducting the number of ways for each $z'<Z$ but this is where I'm stuck - I am not sure how to calculate this at each step

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For $Z=1$ it is not too hard you are on a good track there.

For $Z>1$ try to remove the undesired ones from all possible arrangements (this trick usually a good approach with "at least" or "no more than" statements)